# Spring Oauth2 CORS issue

Tags: java, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0, cors, spring-security-oauth2

I set CORS to allow few custom headers. Below is the Response Header -

> Response Headers {   "Date": "Mon, 14 Mar 2016 10:11:59 GMT",
>   "Server": "Apache-Coyote/1.1",   "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
>   "Access-Control-Max-Age": "3600",   "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":
>   "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT",   "Content-Type":
>   "application/json",   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":
>   "*",
>   "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
>   "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, Authorization,
>   Content-Type, Authorization_Code, User_Credentials,
>   Client_Credentials" }

Above response header should mean that API can be consumed from all the origins with following headers: `Authorization, Content-Type, Authorization_Code, User_Credentials, Client_Credentials`

I can pass all headers and consume APIs from all origins.

**PROBLEM -**

Requests with Authorization APIs are not being allowed. Authorization is a header with which Oauth token is passed like this - `Authorizatio = Bearer ct45tg4g3rf3rfr5freg34gerfgr3gf` (Bearer token).

> corsclient.js:609 OPTIONS http://54.200.113.97:8080/supafit-api/users
>   sendRequest @ corsclient.js:609(anonymous function) @
>   corsclient.js:647b.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3v.handle @
>   jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
>   /client#?client_method=GET&client_credentials=false&client_headers=Authoriz…nable=true&server_status=200&server_credentials=false&server_tabs=remote:1
>   XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://54.200.113.97:8080/supafit-api/users. Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://client.cors-api.appspot.com' is therefore not
>   allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

**EDIT:**

Here is the Rest Client test of that API -

**Response Header -**

```
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate 
Pragma: no-cache 
Expires: 0
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block 
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://client.cors-api.appspot.com 
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT 
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization_Code
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: User_Credentials
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Client_Credentials 
Content-Type: application/json 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
Date: Mon, 14 Mar 2016 11:19:42 GMT Raw JSON
```

**JSON Response Body -**

> {      "id":78,    "userId":"3465434567",    "coachId":null,
>   "name":"XDCDSC",    "dob":null,    "email":"puneetpandey37@gmail.com",
>   "imageURL":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-TcTQeitAvag/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAA/4pamurzO1a4/photo.jpg",
>   "gender":null,    "userPhysic":null,    "userTypeId":1,
>   "dietitanId":null,    "alternateEmailId":null,
>   "yearsOfExperience":null,    "lastExperience":null,
>   "languagesKnown":null,    "aboutYourself":null,
>   "coreCompetence":null,    "fieldOfWork":null,    "userAddresses":[
>         {
>            "id":1,
>            "userId":78,
>            "locationId":1,
>            "address":"EC",
>            "landmark":"Near BN",
>            "phoneNumber":null,
>            "addressType":"Home"
>         }    ],    "phoneNumbers":[
>
> ] }

Comment: I use this site - www.test-cors.org/ to test CORS request and do not have response. It only tells that the CORS is not allowed. When I test the API from Rest Client, I get 'Authorization' as allowed header, but still CORS issue. Please see the 2nd paragraph of my question above to find the Response Heder. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> The response had HTTP status code 401.

Your server needs authentification for the [Preflight Request](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests), but the client removes credentials as [CORS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0) says:

> Otherwise, make a **preflight request**. Fetch the request URL from *origin* source origin using referrer source as *override referrer source* with the *manual redirect flag* and the *block cookies flag set*, using the method `OPTIONS`, and with the following additional constraints:
>
> Include an `Access-Control-Request-Method` header with as header field value the request method (even when that is a simple method).
>
> If author request headers is not empty include an `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header with as header field value a comma-separated list of the header field names from author request headers in lexicographical order, each converted to ASCII lowercase (even when one or more are a simple header).
>
> - Exclude the author request headers.
> - Exclude user credentials.
> - Exclude the request entity body.

You have to change your server, to allow anonymous access of Preflight Request.